# Spring Bactch writes empty file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to batch programming and I am using Spring Batch. tried to use some online examples but after fixing lot of errors i am getting an empty file. I am trying to read from a simple MySql database and writing to a CSV file. users.csv is located in resource folder. Spent a lot of time to see what wrong I am doing. There is no error message but it is always showing empty file. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me to fix this issue. Here is my code;

BatchConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader(){
        JdbcCursorItemReader<User> cursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        cursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        cursorItemReader.setSql("SELECT user_id,first_name,last_name,email FROM demodb.user");
        cursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());
        return cursorItemReader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor(){
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
        FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("users.csv"));
        
        DelimitedLineAggregator<User> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>  fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{"userId","firstName","lastName", "email"});
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        
        writer.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        return writer;
    }
    
     
    @Bean
    public Step step1(){
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step1")
                .<User,User>chunk(100)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportUserJob(){
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("exportUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

UserRowMapper.class

```
    public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

      @Override
      public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
           User user = new User();
           user.setUserId(rs.getInt("user_id"));
           user.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
           user.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
           user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
          return user;
      }

   }
```

User.class

```
    public class User {
      private int userId;
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private String email;
    
      public int getUserId() {
          return userId;
      }
      public void setUserId(int userId) {
          this.userId = userId;
      }
    
      public String getFirstName() {
          return firstName;
      }
      public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
          this.firstName = firstName;
      }
      public String getLastName() {
          return lastName;
      }
      public void setLastName(String lastName) {
          this.lastName = lastName;
      }
      public String getEmail() {
          return email;
      }
      public void setEmail(String email) {
          this.email = email;
      }
    
   }
```

UserItemProcessor.class

```
    public class UserItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<User, User>{

       @Override
       public User process(User person) throws Exception {
          return person;
       }

    }
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.batch.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
```

MySql db

[image]

**UPDATE**

I could solve the issue with new file new FileSystemResource(). But I was replicating a business use case issue. As I mentioned I am new to Spring batch and I have a requirement to read from a production database where I have only View permission. I come to know that Spring batch uses metadata tables to process the Batch. So is it required to have a write permission to the table ? If that is the case then I wont be able to use spring batch with only View permission in production environment. Is there any way I can work around this ? Overriding any configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

**I have verified this by running this program, is working fine as it is and no issue**

**Issue:**

As I mentioned in the comments below, user is looking at the file at the wrong location.

- User creates a file at `src/main/resources/users.csv`
- User runs the program
- Files gets copied under `target/classes/users.csv`
- Program is writing to the file under `target/classes/users.csv`
- But user was looking the file at `src/main/resources/users.csv`

Comment: Tried but no luck. Same result.

Comment: Yes I did and it prints out the result set

Comment: when you say empty file? it automatically creates an empty file. Or the empty file you created stays empty file?

Comment: the empty file I created stays as empty. Btw thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: ok. So it may be writing somewhere else? just delete the file and see if it is complaining

Comment: where did you create the file?

Comment: Okay I deleted and it was complaining. I created this under resource folder

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease chunk value

> chunk: Indicates that this is an item based step and the number of items to be processed before the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileSystemResource` instead of `ClassPathResource` in your writer's configuration:

```
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("users.csv"));
```